# VisualVM fatal error detected by Java Runtime Environment - question about log file and error

Tags: tomcat, servlets, java, visualvm

I'm using VisualVM to profile my web app on my pc. I want to see if there are any memory leaks and such.

I'm running Tomcat 6.0.29 and jdk SE 1.6 (with update 22). I should note that I downloaded jdk1.6 so that I could download and use VisualVM. My classes are compiled under jdk1.5 though.

After accessing a JSP page that displays images that are retrieved from a servlet (which in turns retrieves them from a db), Tomcat shuts itself down and the profiling in VisualVM stops since Tomcat is no longer running.

A hs_err_pid.log file is generated and it has logged the following :
Note that the spyder.servlets.ImageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet is the servlet that handles image resizing, display and similar functions.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (sharedRuntime.cpp:877), pid=1116, tid=432
#  Error: guarantee((retry_count++ < 100),"Could not resolve to latest version of redefined method")
#
# JRE version: 6.0_22-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03f31c00):  JavaThread "http-8080-6" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=432, stack(0x04d50000,0x04da0000)]

Stack: [0x04d50000,0x04da0000],  sp=0x04d9eb14,  free space=13a04d9eb24k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1fd0f0]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa45c8]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1abfdd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ac2e1]
v  ~RuntimeStub::resolve_virtual_call
J  java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setRect(IILjava/awt/image/Raster;)V
J  sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.setRect(IILjava/awt/image/Raster;)V
j  java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setRect(Ljava/awt/image/Raster;)V+4
j  sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster.setRect(Ljava/awt/image/Raster;)V+2
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.grabPixels(I)V+262
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3b1d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfd5af]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1002a4]
C  [jpeg.dll+0x3112]
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(J[BIII[IIIIII[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGQTable;Z[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGHuffmanTable;[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGHuffmanTable;ZZZI[I[I[I[I[IZI)Z+0
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(Ljavax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata;Ljavax/imageio/IIOImage;Ljavax/imageio/ImageWriteParam;)V+3414
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(Ljavax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata;Ljavax/imageio/IIOImage;Ljavax/imageio/ImageWriteParam;)V+8
j  javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;)V+21
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream;)Z+116
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)Z+57
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.resize(Ljava/io/BufferedInputStream;Ljava/io/BufferedOutputStream;I)V+53
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.getImage(Ljava/sql/Blob;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+190
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+865
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+38
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+400
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+117
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+373
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+158
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+468
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)Z+82
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run()V+41
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3a9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x186591]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3c67]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3cdd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11da00]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e7004]
V  [jvm.dll+0x185f3c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
v  ~RuntimeStub::resolve_virtual_call
J  java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setRect(IILjava/awt/image/Raster;)V
J  sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.setRect(IILjava/awt/image/Raster;)V
j  java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setRect(Ljava/awt/image/Raster;)V+4
j  sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster.setRect(Ljava/awt/image/Raster;)V+2
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.grabPixels(I)V+262
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeImage(J[BIII[IIIIII[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGQTable;Z[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGHuffmanTable;[Ljavax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGHuffmanTable;ZZZI[I[I[I[I[IZI)Z+0
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.writeOnThread(Ljavax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata;Ljavax/imageio/IIOImage;Ljavax/imageio/ImageWriteParam;)V+3414
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.write(Ljavax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata;Ljavax/imageio/IIOImage;Ljavax/imageio/ImageWriteParam;)V+8
j  javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;)V+21
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/imageio/stream/ImageOutputStream;)Z+116
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)Z+57
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.resize(Ljava/io/BufferedInputStream;Ljava/io/BufferedOutputStream;I)V+53
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.getImage(Ljava/sql/Blob;Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+190
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+865
j  spyder.servlets.imageProcessing.ImageProcessingServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+3
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+35
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+38
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+400
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+117
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+804
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+373
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+64
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+42
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+158
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)V+468
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Ljava/net/Socket;)Z+82
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run()V+41
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x030e3800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3276, stack(0x04f10000,0x04f60000)]
  0x03014400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3736, stack(0x04dd0000,0x04e20000)]
=>0x03f31c00 JavaThread "http-8080-6" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=432, stack(0x04d50000,0x04da0000)]
  0x0300a400 JavaThread "http-8080-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1860, stack(0x04d00000,0x04d50000)]
  0x030e9400 JavaThread "http-8080-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1524, stack(0x04cb0000,0x04d00000)]
  0x0328d400 JavaThread "http-8080-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3844, stack(0x04c60000,0x04cb0000)]
  0x03296400 JavaThread "http-8080-2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2704, stack(0x04c10000,0x04c60000)]
  0x040b3c00 JavaThread "http-8080-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3008, stack(0x03a30000,0x03a80000)]
  0x03078400 JavaThread "*** Profiler Agent Special Execution Thread 3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3228, stack(0x04bc0000,0x04c10000)]
  0x03023c00 JavaThread "*** Profiler Agent Special Execution Thread 6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1948, stack(0x03b20000,0x03b70000)]
  0x02b98400 JavaThread "*** JFluid Monitor thread ***" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1300, stack(0x03ad0000,0x03b20000)]
  0x02f18400 JavaThread "*** Profiler Agent Communication Thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3352, stack(0x03a80000,0x03ad0000)]
  0x03177400 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(3)-192.168.0.102" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3152, stack(0x039e0000,0x03a30000)]
  0x02fc3400 JavaThread "JMX server connection timeout 22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1112, stack(0x03990000,0x039e0000)]
  0x031a5400 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=540, stack(0x03940000,0x03990000)]
  0x031a7c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(6)-192.168.0.102" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2964, stack(0x038f0000,0x03940000)]
  0x030a2c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3296, stack(0x03890000,0x038e0000)]
  0x031a0800 JavaThread "TP-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3984, stack(0x03720000,0x03770000)]
  0x0319f400 JavaThread "TP-Processor4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3876, stack(0x036d0000,0x03720000)]
  0x0319e000 JavaThread "TP-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3044, stack(0x03680000,0x036d0000)]
  0x0319cc00 JavaThread "TP-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1320, stack(0x03630000,0x03680000)]
  0x0319c400 JavaThread "TP-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2024, stack(0x035e0000,0x03630000)]
  0x030a7400 JavaThread "http-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2780, stack(0x03590000,0x035e0000)]
  0x030c0400 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3300, stack(0x03540000,0x03590000)]
  0x0306a000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1772, stack(0x03450000,0x034a0000)]
  0x02aecc00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3840, stack(0x02da0000,0x02df0000)]
  0x02ae7000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2036, stack(0x02d50000,0x02da0000)]
  0x02ae5800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4008, stack(0x02d00000,0x02d50000)]
  0x02ae4000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=460, stack(0x02cb0000,0x02d00000)]
  0x02add400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4032, stack(0x02c60000,0x02cb0000)]
  0x02adbc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2288, stack(0x02c10000,0x02c60000)]
  0x002b7000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=212, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02ada400 VMThread [stack: 0x02bc0000,0x02c10000] [id=784]
  0x02aefc00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02df0000,0x02e40000] [id=3740]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 15986K [0x26990000, 0x28af0000, 0x2a990000)
  eden space 27392K,  45% used [0x26990000, 0x275dc970, 0x28450000)
  from space 3392K, 100% used [0x28450000, 0x287a0000, 0x287a0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x287a0000, 0x287a0000, 0x28af0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 20933K [0x2a990000, 0x2ec40000, 0x32990000)
   the space 68288K,  30% used [0x2a990000, 0x2be01590, 0x2be01600, 0x2ec40000)
 compacting perm gen  total 15104K, used 14872K [0x32990000, 0x33850000, 0x36990000)
   the space 15104K,  98% used [0x32990000, 0x33816050, 0x33816200, 0x33850000)
    ro space 10240K,  54% used [0x36990000, 0x36f0c510, 0x36f0c600, 0x37390000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x37390000, 0x37a2fb78, 0x37a2fc00, 0x37f90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f02000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db47000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d338000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d890000 - 0x6d89f000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d609000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\management.dll
0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d370000 - 0x6d38a000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x76d40000 - 0x76d58000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MPRAPI.dll
0x77cc0000 - 0x77cf2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ACTIVEDS.dll
0x76e10000 - 0x76e35000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldpc.dll
0x76b20000 - 0x76b31000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ATL.DLL
0x774e0000 - 0x7761d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x76e80000 - 0x76e8e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll
0x71bf0000 - 0x71c03000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SAMLIB.dll
0x77920000 - 0x77a13000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7a6000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\rmi.dll
0x6e030000 - 0x6e038000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\lib\visualvm\profiler3\lib\deployed\jdk16\windows\profilerinterface.dll
0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d1fa000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x6d4f0000 - 0x6d515000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\jpeg.dll
0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x60c40000 - 0x60ca9000     C:\PROGRAM FILES\NORTON 360\ENGINE\4.3.0.5\ASOEHOOK.DLL
0x78520000 - 0x785c3000     C:\PROGRAM FILES\NORTON 360\ENGINE\4.3.0.5\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\MSVCR90.dll
0x78480000 - 0x7850e000     C:\PROGRAM FILES\NORTON 360\ENGINE\4.3.0.5\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\MSVCP90.dll
0x6d2e0000 - 0x6d32f000     C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms100m -Xmx192m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\jakarta-tomcat\webapps -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\jakarta-tomcat\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\jakarta-tomcat\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=C:\jakarta-tomcat -Dcatalina.home=C:\jakarta-tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\jakarta-tomcat\temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
JRE_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
CLASSPATH=C:\jakarta-tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin;C:\jakarta-tomcat\bin;C:\MYSQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
USERNAME=frank
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2085992k(695128k free), swap 4023152k(2738324k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_22-b04), built on Sep 15 2010 00:56:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Tue Jan 11 15:39:01 2011
elapsed time: 243 seconds
```

I don't know what to make of this. What specifically is the error here? 
What's strange, is that when I restart Tomcat and access the jsp pages again where the ImageProcessingServlet is used on the page...the crash doesn't happen. I just want to be sure this isn't a serious problem...and one that I will have to be concerned over when my app runs on my vps live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it rather *is* a serious problem - your JVM is crashing. There's not much you can do to debug this, either, all you can do is upgrade your JRE to a later version (the current is 1.6.0_23, as of now) and hope for the best.

edit: You're [not alone, either](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-26000.html).

Comment: On my vps, I have Java 5 with Tomcat 6. My jvm hasn't crashed after accessing these same jsp pages live. I'll download the update now and see if it crashes again locally.

Comment: I downloaded the jdk 1.6 and now VisualVM doesn't recognize that the Tomcat service is even running. Any suggestions?

Comment: @katura: That's a whole new question.